# how to convert single line SQL result into multiple rows?

Tags: t-sql, unpivot

I am developing a T-SQL query in SSMS 2008 R2 which returns one line only.  But the problem is that in this one line there are four fields which I instead want to be unique rows.  For example, my output line looks like:

```
Col. 1   Col. 2   Col. 3   Col. 4
xxxx     yyyy     zzzz     aaaa
```

Instead, I want this to look like:

```
Question    Answer
Col. 1      xxxx
Col. 2      yyyy
Col. 3      zzzz
Col. 4      aaaa
```

I have tried using the UNPIVOT operator for this, but it is not doing the above.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean it is not doing the above?  That is exactly what UNPIVOT is for.  What exactly did you try and how exactly did it not work?  Perhaps just read the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this:

Here is a static pivot where you hard code in the values of the columns:

```
create table t1
(
    col1 varchar(5),
    col2 varchar(5),
    col3 varchar(5),
    col4 varchar(5)
)

insert into t1 values ('xxxx', 'yyyy', 'zzzz', 'aaaa')

select question, answer
FROM t1
unpivot
(
    answer
    for question in (col1, col2, col3, col4)
) u

drop table t1
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44083/1) with a demo.

but you can also use a Dynamic Unpivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('t1') and
               C.name like 'Col%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'SELECT question, answer
            from t1
            unpivot 
            (
               answer
               for question in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is from my data names but it is tested

```
select 'sID', sID as 'val' 
from [CSdemo01].[dbo].[docSVsys] 
where sID = 247   
union 
select 'sParID', sParID as 'val' 
from [CSdemo01].[dbo].[docSVsys] 
where sID = 247 ;
```

But UNPIVOT should work

Answer (score 0):

UNION-ing together your four questions would look like:

SELECT  'column1' AS Question, MAX(column1)  AS  Answer UNION
SELECT 'column2'  ,  MAX(column2)           UNION
SELECT 'column3'  ,  MAX(column3)           UNION
SELECT 'column4'  ,  MAX(column4)

(obv just using the MAX as an example)